# How can my sniper get enough attacks of opportunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, optimization, opportunity-attack

Recently, there's been some talk about starting up an old Pathfinder game again, and I'm a bit worried about my character being able to adequately support her end of a combo that's rather central to the party's combat abilities.

The combo in question is that another character in the party, a flowing monk//master of many styles 9 (the DM let him replace the flowing monk bonus feats with the master of many styles bonus feats in order to get both archetypes, with the requirement he inherit the ex-monk rules section from 3.5), repositions enemies a lot of times each round, and also trips them.  When we stopped playing, he was making at least 4 repositions per round, several times a day making 6 repositions and a trip, and occasionally (via critical hits with Repositioning Strike) making 7. With Combat Reflexes and a Dexterity modifier of +7, I was able to make up to 8 attacks of opportunity: enough to snipe each of the repositioned and tripped targets via Snap Shot and my party members AoO provoking feats, while saving another one just in case something happened.

The issue is that the GM plans, if we start up again, to have us each spend 62K gp and level us up to level 12 (the idea being that we basically never play past level 6 but actually these characters are weak enough (i.e. not full casters) that they might actually fit in with what the content for that level expects).  I know my friend is planning on taking even more stuff to make even more reposition attempts per round, so that I might be looking at 8ish potential attacks of opportunity *every* round, and up to 11 when he uses his 1/day/level archetype thing.  His repositions only work (i.e. are awesome and effective and stuff) if I have the attacks of opportunity to rain fiery death upon the foes he stacks up in a line.  I figured I might have to lose a feat (gp for AoO would be just too easy, wouldn't it) but I can't find anything other than combat reflexes with which to gain extra attacks and I'm pretty sure my dex mod isn't gonna go up enough to make up the difference (It could go up by 1, so I can make 9/round, which is 3 less than I'd need to be comfortable, but I'd rather use the point to boost my Wisdom from odd to even for the bonus to perception checks, sense motive checks, and will saves.  If I do end up putting it in Dex I might want to consider the 5th level of gunslinger for gun training).  I obviously can't take combat reflexes again, so I'm not sure what I can do.

The character in question is a human Scryer 1/Gunslinger 4/Slayer 4.  Alignment (and alignment restrictions) aren't a thing in this campaign (or rather, alignment restrictions are waived and alignment has no consistent metric beyond what the GM feels like at the time), but the character is a decent person so e.g. demonic obediences may not work.  The character doesn't have anything for or against any particular deities at present (though she uses Erasil's Divine Fighting Style via slayer talents that bypass prequisites like worshipping him), just the obediences often involve things like torture and self mutilation, which she's not cool with.

- Her **feats** at present are:

  Combat Reflexes,
  Sacred Geometry,
  Point Blank Shot,
  Rapid Shot,
  Blind-Fight,
  Quick Draw,
  Weapon Focus (X-laser),
  Snap Shot,
  Tenebrous Spell,
  Scribe Scroll,
  Gunsmithing

  Some of those (Weapon Focus and Blind-Fight) are from items, while others (Scribe Scroll, Snap Shot, and Gunsmithing) are class-based bonus feats.
- She also has the Blood Reader slayer talent.
- Her **attributes** are:

  Str 7
  Dex 24
  Con 11
  Int 24
  Wis 17
  Cha 15

  but they could be moved around by swapping out gear if needed.
- Her **traits** are Improvisational Equipment and Metamagic Master (*True Strike*)

What can I do with this character so that she can provide more attacks of opportunity for support?  I have the three levels to spend, but the less it takes from that the better; ideally, I'd spend those levels on slayer and pick up Improved Snap Shot from the talent-based feat chain and Far Shot from normal feat gain.

Whatever it is should not use immediate actions if at all possible; her typical round involves using Sacred Geometry to cast a *Quickened Umbral Tenebrous True Strike* as a cantrip before her attacks and using an immediate action would cut into her swift action supply.  Now that she's a high level and has proficiency in her weapon and a scope and base attack bonus and stuff I suppose that's less of a problem to lose, but she doesn't have precise shot or far shot (yet) and occasionally she's shooting into melee from ~1800 ft and more often shooting into concealment, so the +20 is really nice.

Anything not super-evil is acceptable as a solution, but the less it disrupts the character the better.

Comment: Could you include a section on acceptable methods (or just indicate any method is acceptable)? For instance, is further multi-classing acceptable? Only Feat choices? Retraining? Using the budget you indicated?

Comment: @Ifusaso anything that doesn't involve requiring the character to behave a certain way that's super evil is acceptable, but the less it disrupts the character the better.

Comment: -1 due to illegal use of AoO's. Snap shot only lets you threaten 5ft away.

Comment: @VoromirKadien you don't need to threaten a space to make attacks of opportunity in it.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer What? ["An enemy that takes certain actions while in a threatened square provokes an attack of opportunity from you."](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Attacks-of-Opportunity) Is the idea that the *you* need not be the creature doing the threatening?

Answer (score 2):

There are of course several options, all with some limitations and drawbacks:

- By buying a quicken metamagic rod (lesser) for 35k, you can cast [Line in the Sand](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/line-in-the-sand/) as a Swift Action, giving you 7 more AoOs at your Int of 24. Note that at your current level it will only last 1 round.
- If you can trick your GM (which might be possible, they seem quite generous) into giving you a Mythic level, the Mythic Combat Reflexes feat gives you infinite attacks of opportunity.
- If you don't have a Belt of Incredible Dexterity, a +6 belt will run 36k and yield 3 more AoOs.
- A permanent Reduce Person spell (2.5k cost for the Permanency, plus a willing caster) will give you +2 Dex and yield 1 more AoO (plus the other benefits/drawbacks)
- Making a pact with a succubus can give you +2 Dex yielding 1 more AoO as a profane bonus but will likely cost you more than gold...
- 50k spent on Wishes give you +2 inherent Dex, yielding 1 more AoO. Again, you would need to find a willing caster
- A 1 level dip in Alchemist will allow you to drink a +4 Dex Mutagen, yielding 2 more AoOs, but drinking a Mutagen is a standard action

Comment: *Line in the Sand* only grants attacks against people in a 5ft burst around me, which tends to be just me and my gun.  Otherwise it'd definitely be the way to go, though, cause a 5th level casting would last the whole fight most of the time and that's still just 125 gp/scroll or however much less per casting for a wand.

Comment: Also the quicken metamagic rod wouldn't help, since I can already cast Quickened spells without level adjustment.

Comment: Are you not already limited to 5' AoOs with Snap Shot?

Comment: it seems likely that the GM is being generous with the line in the greater reposition feat saying that all allies get an attack of opportunity

Comment: @Bedro We play a strict RAW game except for discrete, specified exceptions.  The AoO's I'm making are not based on threatened area (e.g. Greater Trip, Greater Reposition) but rather are the result of targets provoking attacks of opportunity from everyone.  Threatening an area is only important for certain kinds of AoOs.

Comment: @Bedro In sum, no, I'm not. Like the question mentions I typically stay over a thousand feet from combat and make my attacks of opportunity from there.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Really? I mean, for example, Greater Reposition says, "Whenever you reposition a foe, his movement provokes attacks of opportunity from all of your allies," yet the foe's *movement* can't provoke attacks of opportunity from your allies if he isn't moving out of or within those allies' threatened areas, right?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer can you give an example of how you get an AoO at 1000 ft?