# Is there a way to make an Attack of Opportunity at 1000 ft+?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack

So this comment in this question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/118665/how-can-my-sniper-get-enough-attacks-of-opportunity/118707?noredirect=1#comment288732_118707) states :

> We play a strict RAW game except for discrete, specified exceptions. The AoO's I'm making are not based on threatened area (e.g. Greater Trip, Greater Reposition) but rather are the result of targets provoking attacks of opportunity from everyone. Threatening an area is only important for certain kinds of AoOs. – the dark wanderer

combined with this statement in the post :

> occasionally she's shooting into melee from ~1800 ft

leads me to believe that RAW you can take Attack of Opportunities from 1800 ft away. We're going to be starting up a new game of pathfinder soon and I want to know how to do this. So I can do this in my game it sounds awesome.

So any race class extra ability or item you can find from official pathfinder sources is fair game **(no consumable items)**. You can even have a friend to help set up the AoO's. If you can do it with the classes and feats mentioned in the question that spawned this bonus points to you. I'm expecting the answer to be no, but I haven't played pathfinder in a while maybe some new rules came out.

Comment: Hi! You should reproduce the comment in the question itself, because comments don't have very long lifespans. They tend to be gone in a matter of hours.

Comment: Hey there! Could you give us a little more detail about the specific problem you face? This site is more geared towards specific problems, rather than broad brush strokes. Are you asking about specific feat and class interactions? Are there any constraints on your question? Just some things to think about to get you closer to an answer.

Comment: Doesn't sound like an exact duplicate to me. One question is asking how to do it, another is asking if a certain feat allows you to do it.

Comment: The answer you quote as a duplicate is only asking about that specific feat. I'm asking how I can take an attack of opportunity at 1000+ feet with current rules. Clearly not a duplicate because Snap Shot has nothing to do with my answer since it won't let you AoO outside of 5ft.

Comment: Alright, but in that case I'd just be switching it back to the Too Broad hold that people voted onto this before.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I thought optimization questions are legit?

Comment: Either very general, or specific builds that need one more thing. This seems to falls between: very specific, but asking for all build details. That probably hits the general Too Broad hold reason that five Close Voters already put on it before. (See [the charop FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1639) for the discussion on what's *not* Too Broad.) I see it's been reopened, but if it's contentious I'll likely re-hold it as Too Broad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there doesn't appear to be a method for a **ranged** Attack of Opportunity, there is one way that I know of to make AoO at that range.

### Gloves of the Shortened Path (Ultimate Equipment)

> Once per day on command, the wearer of these oxblood leather gloves can bend space to extend her reach to **a non-adjacent square within line of sight**. For the next 10 rounds, she can touch anything in that square as if it were her own square, as long as she has line of effect to the target square. She may change the targeted square as a swift action.
>
> When using the gloves to touch, attack, or manipulate anything in the square, the wearer’s arms and hands also appear in that square, allowing creatures and effects to target her as if she were in that square. She cannot use this connection to transfer anything from her square to the target square, or vice versa. If she drops anything, it lands in her square. She can use her hands (including natural attacks from those hands, if any), hand-held objects (such as lockpicks), and **melee weapons** in that square as if she were there. **The square is part of her threatened area, though she cannot use the gloves to provide flanking for herself.** She cannot use the gloves to grapple, make ranged attacks, or make attacks that require her to move out of her actual square (such as a bull rush combat maneuver).
>
> Interacting with the target square is distracting, and anything that threatens her in her actual square automatically flanks her.
>
> If the wearer or her square is blocked from using teleportation or planar travel effects (such as dimensional anchor), the gloves do not function. She cannot use the gloves to target a square protected by such an effect.

[Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-of-the-shortened-path/) Emphasis mine.

Since there is no range listed in the item's description, the only limitation is that the targeted location be a 5' square in line of sight, and not adjacent to you. With open terrain or a sufficient height advantage (such as from flying above the combat area), it should be possible to draw line of sight to a combat taking place outdoors. For the duration, you may use melee weapons as though you occupy the chosen square, and you threaten the chosen square, so you may take AoO against opponents who provoke them in your chosen square.

Now you just need someone to Greater (manoeuvre of choice) someone through the space. A clever GM might also rule that enemies 1000' away have Concealment or Total Concealment due to your poor vision or the intervening terrain / clouds, which would prevent the AoO, but working around that issue is not in the scope of the question.

Comment: Wow I didn't think it was possible thanks. Welcome to the site! I think preparing a scryer sensor could cover the line of sight issues, but you're right that wasn't in the question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not aware of any way to even come close to doing this within the rules as written. Since an Attack of Opportunity requires you to threaten the target, and I'm not aware of any way to extend your threat range that far.

Generally, the easiest way to increase threatened range is to increase size, but that doesn't generally go over 30' for Colossal. Adding a Reach Weapon allows you to threaten 60' away (although no closer than 30' without another special ability).

A Colossal [Animated Object](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/building-and-modifying-constructs/) could be created with an extra 5' Reach. The spell [Long Arm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/long-arm/) can increase your natural reach by another 5', for a total of 70' for a Colossal Reach weapon.

The feat Combat Patrol can extend your threatened area for AoOs by another 5' for every +5 BAB - with a +20 BAB at level 20, our example colossal animated object with reach weapon could now threaten an AoO at 90' distance, still less than 10% of the requested 1000'+.